# Any WPF based Markdown renderer?

Tags: c#, .net, html, wpf, markdown

We have WPF based application. We have separate String repository where the texts are edited in the web. In our WPF application, we use the text from string repository. Our document team use the some of those text from string repository for their html help document. Some texts are cross used in both the application.

The documentation team wants to have inbuilt html texts in the repository so that it can be rendered in html text format. But we do not want to use heavy weight html browser in to the WPF.

Are there any WPF controls which display the markdown directly? With this, WPF can directly support markdown as it is and we can use Markdown Sharp to convert to HTML.

I referenced the following post, but there are old enough now.

[Markdown for C#/WPF Project (MarkdownSharp)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536324/markdown-for-c-wpf-project-markdownsharp)

[Lightly styled text library for WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261068/lightly-styled-text-library-for-wpf)

WPF Html Text Block from Code Project. Looking at implementation, markdown to wpf might be easy..

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/htmltextblock.aspx

Comment: Sorry i'm not sure i fully interpretted the intention here correctly ... you want to have document "snippets" rendered by your application from html strings in your db ... but you don't want to use a browser is what i thought i read ... but that doesn't make sense ...

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [this demo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa972129.aspx) to convert HTML to XAML and render it in WPF.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest would be to use WPF's [WebBrowser control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.aspx) I guess if that doesn't counts as a

"heavy weight html browser in to the WPF".

.