# Rich text editor for metro apps

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro, rich-text-editor

I need a rich text editor for metro apps, I hope the editor stores the data as html, because in the database there are already tons of html based data. Any recommended?

Comment: If there's none ready to use, I would take a look at MarkDown(anyway full featured WYSIWYG editor for regular user produces crappy html) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614068/any-wpf-based-markdown-renderer

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Rich Edit Box...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.richeditbox

I'm not quite sure whether you can get HTML or not...

**UPDATE**

It handles RTF and not HTML. You'll have to write your own *translator*. Check the following link.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/50bdd84b-03c1-45bd-a3a6-b960954b54fc/